# JsonArray в java экранирует \ и записывает по итогу \\

Tags: java, json

Когда я хочу записать '\' в jsonARRAY он сам его автоматически экранирует и портит строку.
например "\u0432" запишется как "\\u0432".

org.json

Answer (score 0):

При декодировании JSON-объекта такая конструкция должна автоматически раскодироваться в нужную строку

Comment: Даже не знаю, если открыть любыми текстовыми редакторами то видно 2 кавычки, а мне надо чтобы было не видно.